# How are COM ports derived and recorded on windows?

Tags: windows, registry, port

I'm writing a device detection function for Windows (XP and greater) that needs to detect newly connected ports and return their VID/PID values.  But, I have absolutely no idea how COM ports on Windows are derived and recorded.  Looking through the system Registry it looks like Windows stores some information, such as the VID, PID and port ID (i.e. COM1 COM26).  Is that port unique to that device?  Or can multiple entries have the same port ID?

Also, if anybody knows of a good and complete tutorial about windows COM ports it would be immensely appreciated.  thanks!!

Comment: There's a bunch of issues here.  For example, COM port#'s are configurable (from Windows device mgr).  And COM ports can be allocated dynamically (e.g. for USB virtual COM ports).  And stuff that's true for one version (e.g. Windows XP) isn't necessarily true for later versions (e.g. Windows 7 or Windows Server).  Your BEST bet is to get the Windows DDK for your specific platform (e.g. Windows 7) if you haven't already done this.

Comment: I'm actually writing the driver in python, and the only tools I have at my disposal are pyserial (which HAS a utility to list ports, but it doesn't work very well.  It only lists port 3 and 4) and the built in python libraries (i.e. winreg).  I was hoping to just use winreg to look at the current active ports and compare them to the recorded ports (since it looks like windows records all LocalMachine/Sytsem/CurrentControlSet/Enum/USB), but I have no idea if this is a valid solution or not since I have no idea how windows names ports!

Comment: I m confused? You are talk about USB or serial/COM ports. Because this is not same. Serial port devices dont have vid/pid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all COM ports that have been assigned on the system, then do then you can use the COM Name Arbiter. The Windows I/O Subsystem will assign values based off of the COM Name Arbiter key in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter

The COMDB value in this key, which is a REG_BINARY type, contains masks that show which COM ports have been allocated by Windows. This list is formatted in a little endian fashion, so the first byte represents COM1 through COM8, the second value represents COM9 through COM16, and so on. If the first byte is 0x05, which in binary is 00000101, so COM1 and COM3 have been assigned.

It sounds like you are using a USB to UART bridge device, so while some of these COM ports will be assigned they may not be plugged in to the system when you perform your scan. So you will probably want to do a quick CreateFile(), check-for-success, CloseHandle() sequence to check the validity during your enumeration.

Alternatively, if you are indeed using a USB to UART Bridge, if you just want to get the COM Port for the a specific VID and PID it's possible this is stored in the registry under the device specific key. However this will be dependent upon your hardware vendor's driver and enumeration sequence.